# The best overloaded method match for <type> has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, mvp

I'm getting an error when I hit the following line of code:

```
using (_client = new RestClient("url", this))
```

**Error:** The best overloaded method match for 'MyNamespace.RestClient(MyNamespace.MyPresenter, string)' has some invalid arguments

I've looked at a million of these "The best overloaded method match for" threads, but my issue seems to be something different. The detailed compiler output says it cannot convert from:

MyPresenter [C:\path\to\class\file] to
MyPresenter [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3d988ef4\66e82b30\assembly\dl3\995d0d63\042c184e_aae2cf01\ProjectName.DLL]

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. The types are the same.

Here's my full code (MVP pattern in ASP.net):

```
// default.aspx.cs (View class)
public partial class MyView : Page
{
    private readonly MyPresenter _presenter;

    public MyView()
    {
        _presenter = new MyPresenter(this);
    }

    public TextBox OutputText
    {
        get { return outputText; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

    protected void GoButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        _presenter.DoStuff();
    }
}

// default.aspx.designer.cs
public partial class MyView
{
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button goButton;
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox outputText;
}

// MyPresenter.cs
public class MyPresenter
{
    private RestClient _client;

    public MyPresenter(MyView view)
    {
        View = view;
    }

    public MyView View { get; private set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        **using (_client = new RestClient("url", this))** // Error here
        {
            _client.DoClientStuff()
        }
    }
}

// RestClient.cs
public class RestClient
{
    private readonly MyPresenter _presenter;
    private readonly string _url;

    public RestClient(string url, MyPresenter presenter)
    {
        _presenter = presenter;
        _url = url;
    }

    public void DoClientStuff()
    {
        _presenter.View.OutputText.Text = "Doing client stuff";
    }
}
```

Comment: `I can give some more details about my class structure if necessary`, more details? what is the info you give to us in question?

Comment: your best bet here `SuperFly` is to show some code..

Answer (score -1):

You have your parameters backwards

```
using (_client = new RestClient("url", this))
```

should be

```
using (_client = new RestClient(this, "url"))
```

Comment: Whoops, that was a transcription error. It's not like that in the real code. It's now fixed in my post.